# Nginx ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS when using proxy_pass with a simple setup

Tags: nginx

Let me jump right into it. Here's my setup, with the domain names altered:

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

# Redirect all non-HTTPS to non-WWW HTTPS
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name "~^(?:www\.)?(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Redirect WWW HTTP to non-WWW HTTP
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^www\.(.*)$";
    return 301 https://$1$request_uri;
}

# Reverse-proxy to http://nodejs
server {
    listen 4430;
    server_name "~^(?!www\.).*$";

    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webflow.test.co;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    }

    location ~ /(?<all>.+) {
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Basically, and this isn't done yet, but a basic test, all I'm trying to do is redirect the homepage to our new domain at `webflow.test.co` and everything else to the NodeJS server. This works fine if I change the location / `proxy_set_header Host` to `webflow.test.co`, but fails with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS if I set it to `$host`, which is obviously necessary to preserve the URL. It also fails if I manually set the header `Host` to `test.co`.

Let me know if you need any additional information - I'm so, so very close to solving this drawn-out problem, and I'll accept the first sensible answer that works!

Comment: Have you checked where exactly the redirects are coming from?